Network Error when trying to retrieve json file in GitHub pages
I am coding a sort of win rate calculator for a game, and part of that requires it to retrieve game data that was stored in a json file. This json data was stored in the same repository and branch as the rest of the files. It continues to give me network errors when I try to retrieve it, and it seems that in the network tab in google dev tools it shows that the request was blocked.
I tried moving everything to a different branch, checked my connection, tried to disable some security policies, but I didn’t know how to locate them so I was unsuccessful. I tried changing the path to the file, but none of it worked. Anything would be helpful, I’ll link the repo below
https://github.com/CoderScott2023/PolyFesser/tree/gh-pages

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I took a look at the code and played a little with your page and I was not having any network errors thrown at me. The only thing that I have found is that your page reloads due to the form submit (which for further testing I did disabled locally). Can you provide any information on how one might reproduce your problem?

I was using the firefox browser, but other than that I can't think of anything else that would be different

The reason it isn't working is because the button has a type="submit" so it will redirect you (the formaction attribute is not specified so it redirects you to the same URL) as soon as you click it so it doesn't have time to process anything. One possible solution (there are other ways so solving this issue): make the button have a type="submit".
